# MySQL count and group by query slow even with indexing

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, aggregate-functions

I have a simple query

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM my_table 
WHERE someId = 11 AND userId != 0 
GROUP BY userId 
ORDER BY c DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I have index on `userId` and `someId`, However, in each case, the query took 2,5s on table with 1M rows.

Explain output gives me:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra 
1   SIMPLE         my_table  ref    userId,someId  someId     4        const    6895    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I have also tried to create two-column index on `(someId, userId)` or `(userId, someId)` but speed was also the same.

Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` with removed additional unused columns

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `someId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  #some other unused colums
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `someId` (`someId`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=746173
```

Result of `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'my_table`

```
Name    Engine  Version     Row_format  Rows    Avg_row_length  Data_length     Max_data_length     Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time     Update_time     Check_time  Collation   Checksum    Create_options  Comment     Max_index_length    Temporary   
my_table    InnoDB  10  Dynamic     728295  162     118079488   0   125009920   19922944    746173  2022-08-22 19:47:41     NULL    NULL    utf8_general_ci     NULL            0   N
```

Comment: How much does it take to run without the index?

Comment: Approx two times slower (4 - 5s)

Comment: `(someId, userId)` should be optimal. A limiting factor is probably the number of rows with `someid=11`. MySQL thinks it's 7k, 2.5s sound more like 2-300k though, can you check that?

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'my_table';  for analysis.  We need to see current table structure and indexes.

Comment: @Solarflare The count is correct, tis around 7k

Comment: ventusky.com is just TOO cool.  Looking forward to seeing the SCT and STStatus reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions to consider,

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX my_table_ndx_someid_userid (someid, userid);
```

for a covering index.

Change in the query,
WHERE someid = 11 AND userid != 0
to
WHERE someid = 11 AND userid > 0
for positive testing of value.

What is the new timing?

Comment: Did not helped. However, I have reinstalled mysql and time dropped to 0.3s with the same settings as before. With this updated query, it takes 0.5s

Comment: Please current TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;  and B) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (updated query). Thanks

Comment: It seems that your solution is working, but I have some other problem with database itself. The time varies after every server reset.

Comment: How long does my query take with the covering index?  
Please document  date/time of events one line per event of server reset, query content for each time run and time to complete.  And please post text results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%at%';  If could be you are encountering the 'warm up' cycle after reset.